# Transformation return extra data

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

i have is working with is xml. The problem is when i apply transforms the result contains extra characters and i dont know why

that is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl"
 href="file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/My%20Documents/Test/XsltModelo.xslt"?>
<nyfile>
   <HourNow>20140820230732</HourNow>
   <Customer>
        <ReportType>102,0x00000066</ReportType>
        <BusinessDate>20140820</BusinessDate>
      <Mix>
        <ProductName>noname</ProductName>
        <FamilyGroup>6</FamilyGroup>
    </Mix>
   </Customer>
</nyfile>
```

and it the xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Items>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>    
        </Items>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Mix"> 
        <item>
            <BusinessDate><xsl:value-of select="../BusinessDate" /></BusinessDate>   
            <ProductName><xsl:value-of select="ProductName" /></ProductName>
        </item>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

after apply transform

the xml result contains extra characters 20140820230732102,0x0000006620140820, 
someone could show the light?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Items>20140820230732102,0x0000006620140820
<item>
    <BusinessDate>20140820</BusinessDate>
    <ProductName>noname</ProductName>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only define a template for the `Mix` element, but you are applying templates to everything from the `nyfile` down. Therefore everything apart from the `Mix` will be processed by the default template rules, which recurse over elements but output only text nodes.

If you only want the `Mix` section to be processed, simply select just that:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Items>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="nyfile/Customer/Mix"/>    
    </Items>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. but exist one problem Customer is variable can exist Customer, Customer1, customer2, customer3.  Can i set in  select some how "nyfile/Customer*/Mix" ?